# spring-boot extended authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I've a spring boot application, for which I'm trying to implement a custom authorization schema extending the standard `@RolesAllowed`.

I've created a custom `AccessDecisionManage`r wich reads the `@RolesAllowed` and if there is an argument annotated with my custom annotation I will check if the user has the specified role within the specified scope.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/user/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RolesAllowed("manager")
public List<User> userList(@PathVariable("id") @AuthScope Project project) throws NotFoundException {
            return projectService.findUsersByProject(project);
}
```

I've implemented an `AccessDecisionManager` with the logic required for my custom authorization schema now I'm having trouble configuring my application security to use this `AccessDecisionManager`.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                    .httpBasic();
    }
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
AccessDecisionManager does not support secure object class: class org.springframework.security.web.FilterInvocation
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong ?
Cheers

Comment: Do you really need the custom stuff. Isn't it something you could do with a `@Secured` annotation with some EL magic?

Comment: Or using the Sprnig Security `Pre/Post` authorization.

Comment: I realize that what I want to do can be accomplished either by:
-acessDecisionManager;
-pre-post-annotations;
-secured-annotations;

The problem perssist, once I have to do my custom authorization, either on accessDecisionManager, as I'm doing now, or changind this logic to @Secured or pre-post annotations. At the end I've to configure my aapplication security to use this logic, that's my problem right now.

Comment: If you don't have a custom configuration you don't need to configure anything as it will then just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for your `AccessDecisionManager` to be applied to an HTTP filter chain (by bunging it in the `HttpSecurity`), but (without seeing the code) I am guessing that it isn't meant to support that. It's more likely to work with `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`. I think you need to extend that class add override the `accessDecisionManager()` method. Example here: https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/.

Answer (score 0):

You are right @Dave, that's how I manage to get it working.

```
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        return new AuthScopeDecisionManager();
    }
}
```